# What did I miss to send a http part post request

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, multipart

I am trying to send an image using http multipart request (later I will add another image)

I did this:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://localhost:8080/ServletExample1/multipart1");
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type",
            "multipart/related; boundary=HereItGoes");
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("./test.txt"));
    builder.addPart("bin", bin);
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler()
            .handleResponse(response);
    System.out.println(responseString);
```

on the server, I print the number of parts, using this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    Iterator<Part> partsIterator = request.getParts().iterator();
    System.out.println("The number of parts is :" + request.getParts().size());
```

and the answer is always zero, what mistake did i do ?

#### Update 1

as @Jon Skeet, I was creating the request before adding the file. Now I reordered the code in which I put the `execute` as the last line, and I still get the same thing, on the server the number of parts, is still zero

Comment: suddenly someone down vote :) without any comment, any thing, he/she just  down votes . lol

Answer (score 1):

Look at when you're calling `execute` - that's before you build the request properly! Just reorder your code so that you fully build the request, *then* you post it to get a response, *then* you use the response. (I'd also be personally surprised if using a URL in a `File` constructor worked, but maybe there's something funky going on there... normally `File` refers to a local filesystem file...)

Comment: Okay, I was stupid to not see my error. thank you, but now when i did the correct request, i got this exception: `java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket`. Any suggestion please? (accepted answer)

Comment: @Marco: I think you should ask a new question with more details.

Comment: kindly check my update, it seems your solution wasn't 100% correct, because I re ordered the code and i still see in the server that i am having zero parts, the files is there, i parse it, checked its content, and it is in the correct location. i don't know why on the server i am still having the number of parts is zero , could you help please.