# Java servlet can't receive the parts of an http post multipart request

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, multipartform-data, multipart

First, I asked this question [What did I miss to send a http part post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653838/what-did-i-miss-to-send-a-http-part-post-request) and it seems i didn't understand the logic of sending multipart from a client to a server. Using this post https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/mylibrary-files-api/file-add-multipart-post.html I was able t see the required fields in each part.

I build my request and added all the required fields as you see here

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://localhost:8080/ServletExample1/multipart1");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type",
                "multipart/related; boundary=HereItGoes");
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("./test.txt"));
        builder.addPart("source", new StringBody("MyComputer",
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("folder_id", new StringBody("-1",
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("file_type", new StringBody("txt",
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("file_name", new StringBody("test.txt",
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("description", new StringBody("The file to test",
                ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("data", bin);
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler()
                .handleResponse(response);
        System.out.println(responseString);
```

my problem is in the server, i keep receive that the number of the parts is zero. for somewho the server is not receiving the parts (note i am not saying there is exceptions in the server)

I am saying this because on the server (my servlet) i do this

```
Iterator<Part> partsIterator = request.getParts().iterator();
            System.out.println("The number of parts is :"
                    + request.getParts().size());
```

and the result of the printing is always zero, always

what am i missing please?

Answer (score 2):

Servlets' multipart configuration expects a `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data`.

This is specified, among other places, in the [javadoc of `@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html)

> Annotation that may be specified on a `javax.servlet.Servlet` class,
>   indicating that instances of the `Servlet` expect requests that conform
>   to the `multipart/form-data` MIME type.

You're specifying a different content type

```
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=HereItGoes");
```

Get rid of this. The `MultipartEntityBuilder` already builds a request with the appropriate headers. Just add

```
builder.setBoundary("HereItGoes")
```

for the boundary.

Example `Servlet`

```
@WebServlet(loadOnStartup = 1, urlPatterns = "/multipart1")
@MultipartConfig()
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("The number of parts is :" + request.getParts().size());
        Iterator<Part> partsIterator = request.getParts().iterator();
        while (partsIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(partsIterator.next().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

It will receive all 6 of the parts you send with the code in your question.

Comment: Brilliant The good thing that your answer works perfectly, the bad thing is that it seems i don't have to specify all these information like description, file name, file type, source and data. right? because i changed there names and the request still working and i can read the new properties on the server. Could you tell me please to any page of link or tutoarial to parse the file in the server? Plus, how can i send many parts :) your code will send just one part.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I don't know what your server is doing, how it's parsing it, what it's expecting, etc.  I've added a sample `Servlet` that receives all parts.